# Welcoming Guest using SQL tables

Tags: php

I have this code currently inside of my page.

```
<?php
        if ($admin->get_permissions()==3)
        echo 'Welcome Administrator';
        elseif ($admin->get_permissions()==1)
        echo 'Welcome User';
        else
        echo 'Welcome Guest';

        ?>
```

Now if you're logged in as an admin or a standard user it works fine, but if you're visiting the site as a guest then it gives the error

```
Call to a member function get_permissions() on a non-object in
```

The error begins at the start of this script. How could I make sure that the get_permissions function works for people logged in and displays custom data for them and also displays information for a guest logged in?
I've been racking my brain around this to no avail. If anybody can help it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: It has nothing to do with sql/mysql. Remove the tag.

Comment: I would have thought calling parameters from a SQL table was SQL related when it calls the permissions table.

Comment: If you look it that way, then you can also tag it with c, c++ as you are using php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `$admin` object isn't created if the user isn't authenticated. To fix this you need to either instantiate the object independently on user authentication or introduce a different check for permissions, maybe something like this:

```
<?php
     if ($admin != null)
     {
        if ($admin->get_permissions()==3) echo 'Welcome Administrator';
        elseif ($admin->get_permissions()==1) echo 'Welcome User';
     }
     else echo 'Welcome guest.';
?>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. You're a lifesaver.

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks like you don't initiate the $admin variable if the person is a guest.  You could us isset() like:

```
if (!isset($admin)){
    echo 'Welcome Guest';
}
elseif ($admin->get_permissions()==3)
    echo 'Welcome Administrator';
elseif ($admin->get_permissions()==1)
    echo 'Welcome User';
```